# Branching strategies on chained branch in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I created `feature-1` branch from `master` then `feature-2` branch from `feature-1` because I needed updates from `feature-1`.

```
master
      `- feature-1
                  `-feature-2
```

I created Pull Request on Azure DevOps for `feature-1` on `master` (with squash commit), when my PR is accepted the branch `feature-1` is deleted.

Now I create PR for `feature-2` on `master`, but here I have conflicts on all edited files even if I had `feature-1` updates (I fixed conflicts in merging (--no-ff) `master` back to `feature-2`).

Is there a way to avoid those conflicts? Is this a good practice or should I create `feature-2` from `master` and merge `feature-1` branch in it instead of creating it from `feature-2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue of getting conflict if I use `Squash merge` when merge from `feature-1` to `master`. You could try to choose `merge` or `rebase` merge type when you merge from `feature-1` to `master`:

[image]

More information of merge type, you could refer to the following link:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/pull-requests-with-rebase/

Comment: Thanks! Next time I use this :)